# How to write dynamic code for multiple regression model automatically calculate r-square values and output data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I have a csv file like this,

```
T_yield Rain    PH  EC  OC  N   P   K   S   Zn  Fe  
6854.5  85.25   1   0   0   0   2   2   2   1   1   
4494.2  75.475  1   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   1   
1449    43.56   1   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   1   
4024.3  127.9   1   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   
2659.2  81.89   1   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   
4807.1  49.02   1   0   0   0   1   2   2   1   1   
1845.8  37.35   1   0   0   0   1   2   2   1   0   
4599.2  98.26   1   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   
4811.7  82.36   1   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   1   
4796.6  66.52   1   0   0   0   1   2   2   1   1   
1806.7  41.75   1   0   0   0   1   2   2   1   1
```

Where T_yield is dependent variable and Rain , EC , OC ....Fe are independent variables.

I want to check which multiple model is good fit for calculate T_yield.

For example :
1) T_yield = b0  + b1* Rain

2) T_yield = b0  + b1 *PH

3) T_yield = b0 + b1 * Ec

:

:

11)T_yield = b0 + b1*Rain  + b2*PH

12) T_yield = b0 + b1*Rain + b2*EC

:
:

T_yield = b0 + b1*Rain + b2*PH + b3*Ec + b4*OC + b5*N +b6*P + b7*K ....So on.
So, How to write a dynamic code for multiple regression which will display all types of combination with r-square value,

I am using this code :

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('/home/desktop/regression.csv')
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
lm = smf.ols(formula='Total_yield ~ Rain', data=data).fit() 
lm.summary()
```

So, I can get r-square value for Rain.
Next I have add next independent variable .

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
lm = smf.ols(formula='Total_yield ~ Rain+ PH', data=data).fit() 
lm.summary()
```

Next I can get r-square value for Rain +PH

Next Again add another variable.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
lm = smf.ols(formula='Total_yield ~ Rain+ PH+EC', data=data).fit() 
lm.summary()
```

So on.So is there any way it will automatic print r-square value with all types of multiple model ?

Comment: All your examples can be combined into b0 + b1*Rain + b2*PH + b3*Ec + b4*OC + b5*N +b6*P + b7*K ... where unwanted independent variables will be set to 0. Eg. setting b2 .. b7.. =0 will become b0+b1*Rain. Maybe this hint can help

Comment: @VivekKumar   I am not get it, can you gives some hints please?

Comment: The difference between `b0 + b1*Rain + b2*PH` and `b0 + b1*Rain` is that `b2` is zero in the second case. If you run the regression with `b0 + b1*Rain + b2*PH` and `T` turns out to be independent from `PH` then `b0` will be (close to) zero. So just run the regression against all variables and observe the resulting parameters.

Comment: correction: it is `b2` which will be close to zero, sorry for the confusion. [Off topic: can moderators edit older comments?]

Comment: @PeterE is correct. Thats what I wanted to tell. You dont need to run any multiple regressions over all such combinations. Just run regression with all features. If any feature do not effect your yield, then its coeff will be close to 0.

Comment: Also first standardize your data before training.

Comment: Okay, @VivekKumar, So Only I have use  to my 10 features only? and check where I have get P values significant or not?

Comment: @VivekKumar, for standardize my data I have use minmax scaler or robust scaler ?

Comment: @PeterE , thanks, So If b2 will be negative instead of 0 then what we have to do ?

Comment: any non-zero coefficient means that the corresponding parameter influences `T`.

Comment: i have get r-square : 0.85 , adjusted r-2 : 0.75 , and p values for Rain , Zn and K are < 0.05 , so this 3 independent variables we choose , right?

Comment: show us which algorithm you used and code also. What is P value?

Comment: @VivekKumar , I have use same code what i have post it. So, is not correct code?

Comment: The code is correct, but there is no need to do it. I have posted the explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I and @PeterE were suggesting was that instead of using multiple lines and multiple training for different independent variables, use only one time with all independent variables.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('/home/desktop/regression.csv')
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
lm = smf.ols(formula='Total_yield ~ Rain+PH+EC+OC+N+P+K+S+Zn+Fe', data=data).fit() 
lm.summary()
```

i.e use all independent variables only once. **Dont do it manually for all different combinations. The algorithm is smart enough to decide which variables to keep and which one to not.**

This results in output:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                T_yield   R-squared:                       0.609
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.348
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     2.335
Date:                Tue, 28 Feb 2017   Prob (F-statistic):              0.169
Time:                        10:40:16   Log-Likelihood:                -91.598
No. Observations:                  11   AIC:                             193.2
Df Residuals:                       6   BIC:                             195.2
Df Model:                           4                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept    237.3697    150.151      1.581      0.165      -130.037   604.776
Rain          46.8455     27.206      1.722      0.136       -19.726   113.417
PH           237.3697    150.151      1.581      0.165      -130.037   604.776
EC          3.591e-13    2.4e-13      1.499      0.185     -2.27e-13  9.45e-13
OC          5.245e-15   2.75e-13      0.019      0.985     -6.67e-13  6.77e-13
N                   0          0        nan        nan             0         0
P           1970.3552   1727.567      1.141      0.298     -2256.848  6197.558
K            474.7395    300.302      1.581      0.165      -260.073  1209.552
S            474.7395    300.302      1.581      0.165      -260.073  1209.552
Zn         -2877.5614   1582.540     -1.818      0.119     -6749.898   994.775
Fe          -575.9214   1194.274     -0.482      0.647     -3498.205  2346.362
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        2.245   Durbin-Watson:                   2.342
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.325   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.892
Skew:                           0.010   Prob(JB):                        0.640
Kurtosis:                       1.605   Cond. No.                     1.68e+35
==============================================================================
```

As you can see, the `coef` values for `EC`, `OC`, `N` are 0 or very close to 0. This means that the T_yield is mostly independent of them. This can be confirmed from your data because all values in EC, OC and N are 0.

Comment: If coef values for EC , OC, N are very close to  0 ,then we select this 3 or delete this 3 feautures?